# Android - Service creation error

Tags: android, android-service

Hello i am creating a service in android. In the service i want my code to run periodically every 5 mins. I using a thread for the same.

Below is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Thread thr = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{}
        }
   };
    while (true) {

        // Some code1

        thr.start();
        while(thr.isAlive()){}

        //some code 2
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error

> 09-24 21:34:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(12393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-24 21:34:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(12393): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.find.your.friend.iith.updateService: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.

Can you please tell me where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a thread that is already alive. As `while(true)` executes forever, `thr.start()` is called again and again. Try:

```
while (true) {

    // Some code1

    if(!thr.isAlive()) {
        thr.start();
    }
    while(thr.isAlive()){}

    //some code 2
}
```

Comment: More to the point, you can't start a thread that's been started before, even if it's been stopped. It will throw an IllegalThreadStateException

Comment: What other ways can I make my while loop "wait for some time" and then execute the rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use alarm service? It is the best solution for your problem.